# Set the space size of matplotlibs linestyle "dashed"

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, linestyle

Is there any way to set the space size/thickness between consecutive dashes when plotting using the `linestyle` `"dashed"`?
What I am looking for is to have the freedom to plot using the following linestyles:

```
-----
-  -  -  -
-     -     -    -
```

Included below is a short piece of code. I was thinking that this would be a matter of linestyle options. However, could not find it, nor in the archive of SO.

```
import numpy

x = numpy.linspace(0, 100, 101)
y = x

plt.plot(x, y, "r", linestyle = "dashed")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line2D instance have the property [`dashes`](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_dashes), which is a sequence of numbers. The first item is the length (in points) for the first on-segment, the second one for the off-segment, the third one on, and so on. The sequence is cycled over the entire length of the line.

So `(10,5)` means: 10 points on-ink, 5 points off-ink, and so on...

Here you go:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 100, 101)
y = x

plt.plot(x, y, "r", linestyle = "dashed", dashes=(10,5)) # short gap
plt.plot(x, y+5, "r", linestyle = "dashed", dashes=(10,20)) # long gap
plt.plot(x, y+10, "r", linestyle = "dashed", dashes=(5,5,5,5,5,15,15,5,15,5,15,15,5,5,5,5,5,35)) # SOS
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a sequence of on/off dashes for your line as follows:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = numpy.linspace(0, 100, 101)
y = x

plt.plot(x, y, "r", linestyle="dashed", dashes=[3, 1, 2, 8])
plt.show()
```

This means that the line will be '3 dashes on, 1 off, 2 on and 8 off', before the cycle repeats. You can customize the sequence you pass in as appropriate.